# Gnome clock on UTC, not local

Tags: gnome, gentoo, timezone, clock

My OS is Gentoo. My Hardware Clock is set to UTC. The `date` command returns the correct time and timezone (EDT). However, my GNOME clock is set to UTC. I have 2 clocks, one at Internet Time, and one set (the format string) to "24-hour".

I have NTP and NTPD installed and running. My timezone/location in the menu that shows up when I click is correct. Even the analog clock right next to it is correct. However, the time that shows up whenever I send emails, whenever I access the internet, is off by 4 hours.

Any advice would be welcome.